# Как запустить таймер после сброса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру, есть код, который каждые десять секунд выводит «Привет». И после нажатия на button мы очищаем интервал (`clearInterval`). Дальше по истечении минуты у меня запускается функция, в которой я передаю функцию, содержащую таймер, — но он уже не работает.

Как правильно после сброса таймера опять его вызвать?

Comment: никак - запустить новый таймер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

никак - запустить новый таймер

Comment: А можно пример ? Просто немогу понять как лучше сделать. При нажатии на батон мы к примеру вырубаем таймер , а включаем при нажатии на другой batton ?

Comment: @Dementiy1999, `setInterval(function(){...}, timeout)`

Answer (score 1):

в чем проблема, вот так с помощью jquery...

```js
var timer = 0,
textBlock = $('#text');

function startInterval(){
clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(function(){
textBlock.append('<h3>Привет</h3>');
}, 1000);
}

startInterval();

$("#start").on('click', startInterval);

$('#stop').on('click',function(){
clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```css
#text{
  border: 2px solid #777;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="start" type="button" value="start timer">
<input id="stop" type="button" value="stop timer">
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: если несколько раз нажать на старт - запустятся несколько таймеров, а остановить можно будет только последний:)

Comment: отредактировал, предыдущий убивается перед стартом следующего...